# iOS How to add an object in array at 0 index and show in tableview cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an issue that an array having three main objects and i want to add  one object on each array's 0 index

Here is [URL link](http://api.zameen.com/api4/index.php?request=%7B%22type%22:%7B%22c%22:%22type%22,%22key%22:%22c3fa4900cfbb912e1f0104a5a996042b%22,%22response_type%22:%22json%22,%22a%22:%22find%22%7D%7D)

In three sections Homes Plots and Commercial and i want to add All Homes All Plots and All Commercial in each section and added up their results in each section, mean in each section at top All Homes, All Plots and All Commercial

```
   - (void) loadFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)theDictionary{
    _parent_id = -1;
    _type_id = [[theDictionary objectForKey:@"type_id"] intValue];
    _title = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[theDictionary objectForKey:@"title"]];
    _title_alt1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[theDictionary objectForKey:@"title_alt1"]];
    _title_alt2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[theDictionary objectForKey:@"title_alt2"]];

    if([theDictionary objectForKey:@"parent_id"])
        _parent_id = [[theDictionary objectForKey:@"parent_id"] intValue];

    if([theDictionary objectForKey:@"child_list"])
        _child_list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[theDictionary objectForKey:@"child_list"] componentsSeparatedByString:@","]];
}

+ (void)getTypesWith:(void (^)(NSArray *, NSError *))completionHandler
{
    [ZNetworkManager postDataForBackGround:nil atURL:[ZMappingManager getRequestURLToGetPropertiesTypes] completionHandler:^(NSArray *array, NSError *error)
     {
         NSMutableArray *typesDictionariesArray =[NSMutableArray array];
         NSMutableDictionary* details = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
         if (!error)
         {
             NSDictionary *fetchedDictionary = (NSDictionary*) array;
             if([fetchedDictionary isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] == NO)
             {
                 [details setValue:@"Fetched dictionary is null" forKey:@"desription"];
                 completionHandler(nil ,[NSError errorWithDomain:@"MyDomain" code:1 userInfo:details]);
             }
             else
             {
                 if([[[fetchedDictionary objectForKey:@"meta"] objectForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"200"]){
                     NSDictionary *data = [fetchedDictionary objectForKey:@"response"];
                     if([data isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] == NO)
                     {
                         [details setValue:@"Fetched dictionary is null" forKey:@"desription"];
                         completionHandler(nil ,[NSError errorWithDomain:@"MyDomain" code:1 userInfo:details]);
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         NSArray *allTypes = [data objectForKey:@"type"];

                         if([allTypes count] == 0)
                         {
                             [details setValue:@"Fetched dictionary is null" forKey:@"desription"];
                             completionHandler(nil ,[NSError errorWithDomain:@"MyDomain" code:1 userInfo:details]);
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             NSMutableArray *searchTypes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

                             for (NSDictionary *typeDic in allTypes)
                             {
                                 [typesDictionariesArray addObject:typeDic];
                                 ZZameenType *newType = [[ZZameenType alloc] init];
                                 [newType loadFromDictionary:typeDic];
                                 [searchTypes addObject:newType];
                                 NSArray *arrayforChild = [typeDic objectForKey:@"childs"];
                                 for(NSDictionary *typeChild in arrayforChild){
                                     [typesDictionariesArray addObject:typeChild];
                                     ZZameenType *newChild = [[ZZameenType alloc] init];
                                     [newChild loadFromDictionary:typeChild];
                                     [searchTypes addObject:newChild];
                                     newChild = nil;
                                 }
                                 newType = nil;
                             }

                             NSSortDescriptor *typeID_sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"type_id" ascending:YES];
                             [searchTypes sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:typeID_sort,nil]];
                             [ZGlobals saveSearchTypes:typesDictionariesArray];
                             completionHandler(searchTypes ,nil);
                             searchTypes = nil;
                             details = nil;
                         }
                     }


                 }else{

                 }
             }
         }
     }];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what issue you're having. If you're just wanting to insert objects into an array and a specific index - you'd do something like this:

```
[searchTypes insertObject: addObject:newType atIndex:0];
```

Comment: i have above method to change like this :

Comment: [typesDictionariesArray insertObject:dict atIndex:[typesDictionariesArray count]-1];

Comment: That code inserts the object at count mins 1.. which is not 0 and actually will crash if your array is 0 when adding the first object.

Comment: using -1 its not crashed but in 1st section add All Homes and 2nd index and in 2nd section add All Plots add also at 2nd index but in 3rd section add All Commercial at 1st index